# How to write an ipv6 server script using Python 3.10

Tags: python, server, ipv6, ipv4

- My English is not very good, so I used Machine translation. Please forgive me if I offended you*

I want to use **IPv4** to enable external devices to access my project, but due to gateway issues, I am unable to map the port to a wide area network.

So I tried using **ipv6**,

According to online sources, starting from Python version 3.8, you can use the `python - m http. server -- bind::` command to map the project to an ipv6 address

But it reported an error , and after trying many methods, I still couldn't succeed. How can I achieve access to external devices?

```
OSError: \[Errno 98\] Address already in use

for res in \_socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: \[Errno -2\] Name or service not known
```

This is my environment configuration

- python3.10
- anaconda3

Comment: Looks like a syntax problem. You should post the real command you entered (preferably without additional spaces).

Comment: Looks like your system's IPV6 network is not properly configured in first place. This doesn't seem to be a problem of your python code.

Answer (score 0):

### I have found a solution to the problem

###### The first method

Create a new .py file

```
import http.server
import socket


class HTTPServerV6(http.server.HTTPServer):
    address_family = socket.AF_INET6


Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
server = HTTPServerV6(('::', 8000), Handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Then run it

###### The second method

Direct command line execution

```
python -m http.server --bind :: 5050
```

I guess this may be because IPV6 mode of http.server does not have a default port number. If you run it directly

```
python -m http.server --bind ::
```

The error will be reported as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "**/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "**/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/http/server.py", line 1291, in <module>
    test(
  File "**/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/http/server.py", line 1240, in test
    ServerClass.address_family, addr = _get_best_family(bind, port)
  File "**/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/http/server.py", line 1223, in _get_best_family
    infos = socket.getaddrinfo(
  File "**/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

*This time I used Python 3.9*

**Anyway, thank you all for your help**

This is my first time using StackOverflow and I am not very proficient. I would like to say '蟹蟹各位了'